# How to execute Linq query and Binding data in Lable of asp.net pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a Linq query:

```
var result = from p in db.Messages
                     join c in db.Students on p.Stud_Id equals c.Stud_Id
                     where (p.Staff_Id == Int32.Parse(userID.Text))
                     select new
                     {
                         c.Stud_Id,
                         c.FirstName,
                         p.BySupervisor
                     };
```

How can I add result to list and binding each value in Lable using DataBinder. Of course, i have already repeater control to databound

Comment: You need to use a `databound` control like repeater or gridview based on your requirement, you can find hell lot of tutorials for this.

Comment: of course, i have already repeater control to databound

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**Create a class**

```
public class stud
{
  public int Stud_Id {set;get;}
  public string FirstName{set;get;}
  public string BySupervisor {set;get;}
}
```

**Then convert dataset into that class's list**

```
var result = (from p in db.Messages
                     join c in db.Students on p.Stud_Id equals c.Stud_Id
                     where (p.Staff_Id == Int32.Parse(userID.Text))
                     select stud
                     {
                         Stud_Id=c.Stud_Id,
                         FirstName=c.FirstName,
                         BySupervisor=p.BySupervisor
                     }).ToList<stud>();
```

**Then bind data with repeater**

```
repeaterControl.DataSource = result ;
repeaterControl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have included the Repeater control(as per your comment) then simply assign the datasource like this:-

```
YourrepeaterControlId.DataSource = result;
YourrepeaterControlId.DataBind();
```

Please note there is **No Need** to materialize your result into a `List<T>`, it will work just fine if you pass `IEnumerable<T>`.

Thus in your case suppose your control looks like this:-

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="YourrepeaterControlId" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="StudIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Stud_Id") %>'>
         </asp:Label>
         <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'>
         </asp:Label>
         <asp:Label ID="lSupervisor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BySupervisor") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Binding your control as I mentioned earlier will work just fine, there is no need to create an extra class.